# Apache Camel FTP error

Tags: java, apache, ftp, apache-camel, sftp

I am working on a piece of code that routes from FTP input to a bean process and then to FTP output. The process takes about 15 minutes to complete and when it finishes, the Camel tries to delete a input file from FTP input route. Currently the FTP server throws an error:

```
13 Jan 2015 18:21:26 DEBUG org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations.deleteFile - Deleting file: ../flex-brazil/Portal_Forn/request_appr/364/NF_4.txt
13 Jan 2015 18:21:26  WARN org.slf4j.helpers.MarkerIgnoringBase.warn - Error during commit. Exchange[org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileMessage@3207779]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException - File operation failed: 421 Timeout (900 seconds): closing control connection.
FTP response 421 received.  Server closed connection.. Code: 421]
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: File operation failed: 421 Timeout (900 seconds): closing control connection.
FTP response 421 received.  Server closed connection.. Code: 421
at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations.getCurrentDirectory(FtpOperations.java:701)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations.deleteFile(FtpOperations.java:224)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.GenericFileDeleteProcessStrategy.commit(GenericFileDeleteProcessStrategy.java:71)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOnCompletion.processStrategyCommit(GenericFileOnCompletion.java:124)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOnCompletion.onCompletion(GenericFileOnCompletion.java:80)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOnCompletion.onComplete(GenericFileOnCompletion.java:54)
at org.apache.camel.util.UnitOfWorkHelper.doneSynchronizations(UnitOfWorkHelper.java:100)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultUnitOfWork.done(DefaultUnitOfWork.java:228)
at org.apache.camel.util.UnitOfWorkHelper.doneUow(UnitOfWorkHelper.java:61)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor$UnitOfWorkProcessorAdvice.after(CamelInternalProcessor.java:613)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor$UnitOfWorkProcessorAdvice.after(CamelInternalProcessor.java:581)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor$InternalCallback.done(CamelInternalProcessor.java:240)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:173)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:401)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileConsumer.processExchange(RemoteFileConsumer.java:99)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:201)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:165)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:187)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:114)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPConnectionClosedException: FTP response 421 received.  Server closed connection.
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:367)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:294)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:483)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:608)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:582)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.pwd(FTP.java:1454)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.printWorkingDirectory(FTPClient.java:2658)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations.getCurrentDirectory(FtpOperations.java:697)
... 25 more
```

There are any parameter to teach the Camel to send keepalives to FTP server to avoid this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to split the whole process into two routes:

1. Reader Route: Only reads the file from the FTP server.
2. Process and Writer Route: This route processes the incoming message and writes a response to the FTP server

The advantage is, that the connection will be closed after reading and deleting without exception.
When a new message will be written back to server a new connection will be created.

The first route can only close the connection, when the process is asynchronous. For this purpose you can use queues for reading and writing e.g. [seda](http://camel.apache.org/seda.html) or [jms](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html).

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to set a bigger timeout option - the default is 30s.

To set the timeout to 15 minutes: `ftp://user@host?timeout=900000`

Keep in mind, however, that the connection may be closed by the FTP server.